# Laravel intermediate data type on query builder

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

i have a date inside a query in laravel. query builder doesn't read my date as a string. i cant put a variable inside the query so i can't use date->format nor explode string..

here is my code..

```
if(isset($input['time']) && $input['time'] != '')
{
    //Useless, laravel cant read this
    $wew = explode('/', $input['time']);
    $time = $wew[0]."-".$wew[1]."-".$wew[2];

    $actlist = DB::table('activity')
    ->join('activity_details', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('activity.id','=','activity_details.activity_id')
             ->where('activity_details.time','>=', (date(str_replace('-','-',Input::get('time')).' 00:00:00',time())) )
             ->where('activity_details.time','<=', (date(str_replace('/','-',Input::get('time')).' 23:59:59',time())) );
    })
    ->orderBy('activity.id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(Config::get('app.conf')['pagin']);
}
```

the `$wew = explode('/', $input['time']);` returns undefined

where did i go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "returns undefined"? There is no such thing as "undefined" in PHP. And explode always returns either an array or FALSE.

Comment: it returns Undefined variable: time

Comment: It's not the returned value but the warning you get. What is the complete warning message? There should be a filename and line number in the message.

Comment: when i use the code below, i got this error 

SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $3 (SQL: select * from "activity" inner join "activity_details" on "activity"."id" = "activity_details"."id" and "activity_details"."time" >= 07-14-2015 00:00:00 and "activity_details"."time" <= 07-14-2015 00:00:00 order by "activity"."id" desc limit 100 offset 0)